# Drop down not working correctly

Tags: jquery, css

When hovering over `Categories` the drop down menu displays but as i move the mouse over the children it is menu constantly disappearing?

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdanz/hvF8P/17/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `mouseout`. Instead, supply two functions to `hover`:

```
$('#category2').hover(function() {
   $('#category2').show();   // This function will be called upon mouseover
}, function(e) {
    $('#category2').hide();  // This one will properly be called on mouseout
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvF8P/20/**

Side note: Inside the functions, instead of using `$('#category2')`, you can also use `$(this)`.

Comment: does function(e) mean opposite then?

Comment: The children menu does not go away if you don't hover over it.

Comment: @TomHubbard That's by OP's design. `#catdrop` is a different element than `#category2`.